# Access 2007 dataBase conectivity in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

when i debug the program the (Insert into statment error is orrured) and hlighted the vcom.executenonquery();.
How can i solve this Error.

```
STRING VSQL = STRING.FORMAT("INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES ((0),'(1)','(2)',(3)", INT.PARSE(TEXTBOX1.TEXT), TEXTBOX2.TEXT, TEXTBOX3.TEXT, INT.PARSE(TEXTBOX4.TEXT));
VCOM.EXECUTENONQUERY();
MESSAGEBOX.SHOW("DATA INSERTED");
VCOM.DISPOSE();
```

Comment: Many things are wrong in your code. I don't know where to start..

Comment: How can i solve this problem??

Answer (score 2):

*Well*, I will try to answer your question completely because there are many things wrong in your code.

First of all, C# is case-sensitive language. Because of that, `string` and `STRING` are not the same. `EXECUTENONQUERY` and [`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well.

Let's analyze your code line by line;

Your first line should be;

```
string VSQL = string.Format("INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}',{3}",
                             int.Parse(TEXTBOX1.Text),
                             TEXTBOX2.Text,
                             TEXTBOX3.Text,
                             int.Parse(TEXTBOX4.Text));
```

Instead of that, you can always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/).

For exmaple;

```
string VSQL = "INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(VSQL);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1").Value = int.Parse(TEXTBOX1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2").Value = TEXTBOX2.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3").Value = TEXTBOX3.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p4").Value = int.Parse(TEXTBOX4.Text);
```

Instead of calling `.Dispose()` method manually, you can/should always use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) as well. It will dispose your database connections and objects automatically.

I assume you using `OleDbCommand`, your full code should be (*if parsing operations and textboxes names are right*);

```
using(OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(OleDbCommand VCOM = con.CreateCommand())
{
    string VSQL = "INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    VCOM.CommandText = VSQL;
    VCOM.Parameters.Add("@p1").Value = int.Parse(TEXTBOX1.Text);
    VCOM.Parameters.Add("@p2").Value = TEXTBOX2.Text;
    VCOM.Parameters.Add("@p3").Value = TEXTBOX3.Text;
    VCOM.Parameters.Add("@p4").Value = int.Parse(TEXTBOX4.Text);
    con.Open();
    VCOM.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("DATA INSERTED");   
}
```

Comment: @SamileeVirux Glad to help. I suggest to read a book about C# and ADO.NET before writing more code.